# EF6 One-to-One Optional Relationship one-directional navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have the following Domain models in a project I am working on, they are

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LoginName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I basically have a `Person` entity and a `User` entity, a `Person` can exist without a `User` but a `User` cannot exist without a `Person`.  I also only want the relationship in EF to be loaded unidirectional (i.e when i load the `Person` entity I want a navigation property to `User` but NOT the other way)

I am finding that I have to create the relational properties on both objects to achieve the relationship mapping and of course do not want this or the overhead of having to check for NULL in one direction, i would rather the `User` entity did not have its `Person` property.

Could anyone help with defining the correct model and relationship mapping to generate the correct EF Code-First configuration and object model at runtime please, I have tried the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOptional(t => t.User)
    .WithRequired(t => t.Person)
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("PersonId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Al that this acheives is loading the `Person` entity with the `User` property of NULL

If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the entities properly:

1. You can specify an required relationship without specifying the type, like `.WithRequired()`.
2. When using `one-to-one` relationship, name of the `key` property needs tobe same in both entities.

Thus, you can simply achieve what you want by using `HasOptional(t => t.User).WithRequired();`.

For the sake of completeness, I am adding the (more or less) full code below:

1. The entities:

   ```
   public class Person
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string Surname { get; set; }
       public virtual User User { get; set; }
   }

   public class User
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string LoginName { get; set; }
       public string Password { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Entity configuration:

   ```
   public class PersonConfig:EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
   {
       public PersonConfig()
       {
           HasOptional(t => t.User).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Database context

   ```
   public class MyDbContext:DbContext
   {
       public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
       public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfig());
       }
   }
   ```
4. Generated initial migration(using `add-migration`):

   ```
   public override void Up()
   {
       CreateTable(
           "dbo.People",
           c => new
               {
                   Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                   FirstName = c.String(),
                   Surname = c.String(),
               })
           .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

       CreateTable(
           "dbo.Users",
           c => new
               {
                   Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                   LoginName = c.String(),
                   Password = c.String(),
               })
           .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
           .ForeignKey("dbo.People", t => t.Id, cascadeDelete: true)
           .Index(t => t.Id);

   }
   ```
5. Seed configuration:

   ```
   protected override void Seed(EF.MyDbContext context)
   {
       var person1 = new Person {Id= 1, FirstName = "Andrew", Surname = "Peters" };
       var person2 = new Person {Id= 2, FirstName = "Brice", Surname = "Lambson" };
       var person3 = new Person {Id= 3, FirstName = "Rowan", Surname = "Miller" };

       context.People.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Id, person1, person2, person3);

       var user1 = new User { Id = 1, LoginName = "Andrew", Password = "Peters" };
       var user3 = new User { Id = 3, LoginName = "Rowan", Password = "Miller" };

       context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Id, user1, user3);

   }
   ```
6. Usage:

   ```
   MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext();

   ctx.People.ToList().ForEach(person =>
   {
       System.Console.WriteLine($"Id:{person.Id}, Name: {person.FirstName} {person.Surname}");
       if (person.User != null)
       {
           System.Console.WriteLine($"Found user, Id:{person.User.Id}, " +
                                    $"Login: {person.User.LoginName}, Password: {person.User.Password}");

        }
   });

   /*
   Output:
   Id:1, Name: Andrew Peters
   Found user, Id:1, Login: Andrew, Password: Peters
   Id:2, Name: Brice Lambson
   Id:3, Name: Rowan Miller
   Found user, Id:3, Login: Rowan, Password: Miller
   */
   ```